# How to render List Items According to Slider Selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list where I can go adding new lines. To add a line I use the plus button, and to remove the line I use the minus button.

But if I don't want to add item by item to my list, I can I can load the list of values that are defined in my json.

I don't know how to load this list (if the user wants to) according to my Slider selection. According to each Slider value a list of values should be created.

Do you know how I can make this rendering of values dynamic?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-butterfly-l8c75?file=/src/App.js). Thank you in advance.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";

import { dataJobParams } from "./List/dataJobParams";

import "./styles.css";

import List from "./List/List";

const App = () => {
  const [checkSwitch, setCheckSwitch] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    [
      {
        label: "Name",
        value: "",
        name: "00"
      },
      {
        label: "Last Name",
        value: "",
        name: "01"
      }
    ]
  ]);

  const handleOnChange = (e, row, col) => {
    const newData = data.map((d, i) => {
      if (i === row) {
        d[col].value = e.target.value;
      }

      return d;
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  const addRow = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      [
        {
          label: "Name",
          value: "",
          name: `${data.length}0`
        },
        {
          label: "Last Name",
          value: "",
          name: `${data.length}1`
        }
      ]
    ]);
  };

  const removeRow = (index) => {
    const _data = [...data];
    _data.splice(index, 1);
    setData(_data);
  };

  const marks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: "Small"
    },
    {
      value: 33,
      label: "Medium"
    },
    {
      value: 66,
      label: "Large"
    },
    {
      value: 100,
      label: "Extra Large"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="switch">
          <Switch
            isChecked={checkSwitch}
            onChange={(e) => setCheckSwitch(e.target.checked)}
          />
          <span>Params</span>
        </div>
        <div className="slider">
          <Slider disabled={checkSwitch} step={33} marks={marks} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <List
        data={data}
        addRow={addRow}
        removeRow={removeRow}
        handleOnChange={handleOnChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";

import AddCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircle";
import RemoveCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircle";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

import "./styles.scss";

const List = ({ data, handleOnChange, addRow, removeRow }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map((items, i1) => (
        <div key={i1} className="content">
          <div className="content-row">
            {items.map((item, i2) => (
              <TextField
                key={i2}
                label={item.label}
                value={item.value}
                onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, i1, i2)}
                variant="outlined"
                name={item.name}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div>
            {i1 === data.length - 1 && <AddCircleIcon onClick={addRow} />}
            {data.length > 1 && (
              <RemoveCircleIcon onClick={() => removeRow(i1)} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

```js
export const dataJobParams = {
  small_data_load: [
    {
      key: "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",
      val: "200"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.default.parallelism",
      val: "20"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.shuffle.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.broadcast.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
      val: "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",
      val: "2g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.maxResultSize",
      val: "6g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.memory",
      val: "10g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.memory",
      val: "26g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.cores",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes",
      val: "1073741824"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes",
      val: "1"
    }
  ],
  medium_data_load: [
    {
      key: "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",
      val: "400"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.default.parallelism",
      val: "40"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.shuffle.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.broadcast.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
      val: "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",
      val: "2g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.maxResultSize",
      val: "6g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.memory",
      val: "10g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.memory",
      val: "26g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.cores",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes",
      val: "1073741824"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes",
      val: "1"
    }
  ],
  large_data_load: [
    {
      key: "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",
      val: "2001"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.default.parallelism",
      val: "72"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.shuffle.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.broadcast.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
      val: "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",
      val: "2g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.maxResultSize",
      val: "6g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.memory",
      val: "10g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.memory",
      val: "26g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.cores",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes",
      val: "1073741824"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes",
      val: "1"
    }
  ],
  extra_large_data_load: [
    {
      key: "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",
      val: "4001"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.default.parallelism",
      val: "72"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled",
      val: "false"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.shuffle.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.broadcast.compress",
      val: "true"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
      val: "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",
      val: "2g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.maxResultSize",
      val: "6g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.driver.memory",
      val: "10g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.memory",
      val: "26g"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.executor.cores",
      val: "4"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes",
      val: "1073741824"
    },
    {
      key: "spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes",
      val: "1"
    }
  ],
  none: [{}]
};
```

Comment: Do you want to load a certain amount of values using you Slider?

Comment: Hey Imonning, Yes, for example if he selects `medium`, I'll render the fields that are in `medium_data_load`. And if the slider is disabled, it will only be the values that it will manually enter.